# Use mocha with grunt-contrib-connect or through filesystem?

Tags: mocha.js, gruntjs

Is it better to use mocha with a local server through the `grunt-contrib-connect` task or just run it with `grunt-mocha`?

What are the differences/downsides of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two totally different things. You do not automatically run spec files with `grunt-contrib-connect`, it is meant to be used in conjunction with other tasks that hit the connect server. You can use it with `grunt-mocha` (see the `urls` option), but it's really only useful if you need to test with server logic. Otherwise, you can mock server responses and XHR requests in your tests using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).